# How can I group (in Scala) rows of a dataframe and can I sum values of a column of this rows?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ev1    ev2    Score    seconds
A      A       9        0
B      E       1        0
C      C       6        8
D      B       3        10
E      D       5        0
A      E       8        0
C      F       6        0
E      C       3        0
F      B       6        11
D      B       7        0
A      B       9        0
D      G       8        0
G      A       6        9
...    ...     ...      ...
```

And I want to group the rows until the values of "seconds" is between 9 and 11 and I want to sum the value of "Score" of these rows.

In output I should have something like this:

```
group    sum
   1     19
   2     28
   3     30
   ...    ...
```

Where the first partition includes the rows with the scores (9 1 6 3) and "sum" (19) is the sum of these values, the second one includes (5 8 6 3 6) and so on.

Comment: how should the rows be *ordered*?

Comment: Do you mean the rows of the output dataframe? I just want the sum of the score for each group of rows, and the groups must be in the same order in which the sum of their row's scores are calculated. For example group 1 includes the sum of first 4 rows of dataframe, group 2 of the next 5 rows and so on.

Comment: @pdap_93 If that helped you, do not hesitate to accept the answer ! Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can use window functions to define your groups.

To define if it is a new group, we need to check if the previous value of `seconds` is between 9 and 11.

```scala
// Some useful imports
import org.apache.spark.sql.{functions => F}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

// Your data with an order defined by monotanically_increasing_id as you are reading it, before any shuffle.
val df = Seq(
("A", "A", 9, 0),
("B", "E", 1, 0),
("C", "C", 6, 8),
("D", "B", 3, 10),
("E", "D", 5, 0),
("A", "E", 8, 0),
("C", "F", 6, 0),
("E", "C", 3, 0),
("F", "B", 6, 11),
("D", "B", 7, 0),
("A", "B", 9, 0),
("D", "G", 8, 0),
("G", "A", 6, 9)
).toDF("ev1", "ev2", "Score", "seconds").withColumn("time_col", F.monotonically_increasing_id)

// Here we are defining the groupId using Window function

val groupIdWindow = Window.orderBy("time_col")

val df2 = df.
withColumn("lagged_seconds", F.lag('seconds, 1, 0) over groupIdWindow).
withColumn("newGroup", ('lagged_seconds > 8 && 'lagged_seconds < 12).cast("bigint")).
withColumn("groupId", sum("newGroup").over(groupIdWindow) + 1)

df2.show
/*

+---+---+-----+-------+--------+--------------+--------+-------+
|ev1|ev2|Score|seconds|time_col|lagged_seconds|newGroup|groupId|
+---+---+-----+-------+--------+--------------+--------+-------+
|  A|  A|    9|      0|       0|             0|       0|      1|
|  B|  E|    1|      0|       1|             0|       0|      1|
|  C|  C|    6|      8|       2|             0|       0|      1|
|  D|  B|    3|     10|       3|             8|       0|      1|
|  E|  D|    5|      0|       4|            10|       1|      2|
|  A|  E|    8|      0|       5|             0|       0|      2|
|  C|  F|    6|      0|       6|             0|       0|      2|
|  E|  C|    3|      0|       7|             0|       0|      2|
|  F|  B|    6|     11|       8|             0|       0|      2|
|  D|  B|    7|      0|       9|            11|       1|      3|
|  A|  B|    9|      0|      10|             0|       0|      3|
|  D|  G|    8|      0|      11|             0|       0|      3|
|  G|  A|    6|      9|      12|             0|       0|      3|
+---+---+-----+-------+--------+--------------+--------+-------+

*/

// And now, a simple groupBy

df2.groupBy("groupId").agg(F.sum("Score").as("Score")).show
/*
-------+-----+
|groupId|Score|
+-------+-----+
|      1|   19|
|      2|   28|
|      3|   30|
+-------+-----+
*/
```